# Cannot logout of a shinyapps.io app

Tags: shiny, logout

I have deployed a Shiny app using [shinyapps.io](http://www.shinyapps.io/) and have made the application private. I can logon to the app using my credentials and use the app, but I am not able to logout of the app.

When I try to out logout of the app I am redirected to the following link:

https://userName.shinyapps.io/appName/__logout__

And the result of this redirect is: Not Found.

I tried to search online( shinyapps-users google group, and Stackoverflow) but failed to get any info.

Comment: Rather than search, post a message to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/shinyapps-users as they suggest on their site. That's the only way to get non-premium support.

Comment: thanks @hrbrmstr, I posted on the group and got a quick response.